# JBOSS and MySql

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu, jboss, datasource

I'm converting JBOSS and MySQL from Windows 2008 R2 to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

In Virtual Windows, have MySQL 9.6 and JBOSS 7.1.1.Final. All is working well. Meaning Windows JBOSS is working and the datasource are configured to connect to Windows MySQL. Able to access the websites, make DB calls, etc.

In Virtual Ubuntu, installed JBOSS 7.1.1.Final and MySQL 9.6. Both apps are running. JBOSS is working well, the datasources are connecting to the Windows MySQL. Dumped Windows MySQL databases to Ubuntu MySQL databases. Created identical users in Ubuntu MySQL to match windows MySQL with same permissions.

```
CREATE USER myDb IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON myDb.* TO 'myuser'@'%';
```

In both JBOSS' when I change the datasource connection string from Windows MySQL to Ubuntu MySQL the connection is never made. I've played around with "my.cnf" file in Ubuntu MySQL and I am able to make connections from other remote machines. Using MySQL Workbench from Windows, I'm  able to make a connection to both MySQL servers (Windows & Ubuntu).

I get the following error in JBOSS:

```
Unknown error
Unexpected HTTP response: 500
Request
{
    "address" => [
        ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
        ("data-source" => "MYSQLDS_myDb")
    ],
    "operation" => "test-connection-in-pool"
}

Response
Internal Server Error
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "JBAS010440: failed to invoke operation: JBAS010447: Connection is not valid",
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

I also ran this to see if Ubuntu MySQL is running and which port it's listening to.

```
root@M1:/# lsof -i -P | grep mysql
mysqld    58737        mysql   11u  IPv6 418152190      0t0  TCP *:3306 (LISTEN)
```

Here is my connection string: `jdbc:mysql://M1:3306/myDb` I've tried using the machine name, the IP address and "localhost" (since Ubuntu JBOSS and Ubuntu MYSQL are on same machine).

My connection string to connect to Windows MySQL is: `jdbc:mysql://W1:3306/myDb` and this works.

Comment: I also added the port to the iptables `$iptables -A INPUT -i lo -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT` & `iptables -A OUTPUT -i lo -p tcp --sport 3306 -j ACCEPT`

Answer (score 2):

Solved my own problem. Somewhat embarrassed but, the database name had be changed to lower case in the import to the Ubuntu MySQL. Therefore, the connection string was incorrect, because I needed to put in the database name in lower case.